Shell script flow interrupted by gradle tasks
Consider the following shell script:
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello
gradle clean
echo Bye

When run by file, the expected output is right.
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ ./script.sh

Hello
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date
Bye

When run by stdin, the expected output is wrong.
$ cat script.sh | bash -s

Hello
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date

Under stdin case, after running gradle clean, the script flow is interrupted, exits with return code 0 and never reaches the next commands. I am searching the way to execute the above script by stdin because I will use a pipe with curl, like curl -so- http://host/script.sh | bash -s.
I could solve it wrapping gradle in a new pipe, but I don't understand why it's working either:
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello
echo gradle clean | bash -s
echo Bye

I would like to find a neat solution (e.g.: a flag in bash/gradle). Thanks.

gradle presumably reads from stdin, so it reads the rest of the script rather than letting the shell read and execute it. If gradle doesn't actually need any input, try using gradle clean </dev/null to keep it from stealing the script as input.

@GordonDavisson Yes, you are right! I test it right now and works like a charm!

As pointed out by Gordon Davisson

gradle presumably reads from stdin, so it reads the rest of the script rather than letting the shell read and execute it. If gradle doesn't actually need any input, try using gradle clean </dev/null

You can reproduce similar errors with
bash -s << 'EOF'
read var
echo "this line is consumed by read"
echo "end of script"
EOF

I don't want to steal Gordon Davisson's answer. If they write an answer, please accept theirs. However, I have something important to add:
When you plan to execute your script using curl | bash -s it would be good to add more general precautions against this and other typical errors.
If your target systems support process substitution then you could wrap your script in
bash <(cat <<'END_OF_SCRIPT'
insert your
entire script
here
END_OF_SCRIPT
)

This prevents at least the following problems

Commands from the script may consume the script from stdin (your problem)
curl downloads the first half of the script, but then fails. The script is only executed half. In such a case, the user would neither get an error message (curl -s is silent, and bash does not know that more commands were supposed to follow, unless you were in the middle of a command block, e.g. if ...; then) nor an exit code (curl may exit with non-zero; but that code is lost in the pipe curl | bash).

You may also want to use bash -e / set -e to stop the script when something like mkdir somedir and/or cd somedir goes wrong. There are a few caveats, but it is better than nothing.

What you can try to redirect stdin for gradle using /dev/null.
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello
gradle clean < /dev/null
echo Bye

